XGBoostError: value -1 for Parameter verbosity exceed bound [0,3]
Error message as in the title. It doesn't make sense to me, per my code below:
clf = xgboost.XGBClassifier(verbosity=1)
print (clf.__class__, clf.verbosity) 
# prints <class 'xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier'> 1
clf.fit(X=train_data_iter[features].fillna(0), y=train_data_iter['y']) # the error is raised here

The value is clearly 1, but it somehow gets -1? I don't get it.

I can't reproduce this, with xgboost 2.0.3.  What version are you using? Can you provide the dataset (and any other code needed) to reproduce the issue?

You can set verbosity to your desired value like below. This solved it for me.
import xgboost as xgb
xgb.set_config(verbosity=1)

Check here for documentation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
